# Как лучше организовать приложение?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

В приложении используется >1000 картинок весом до 100Кб. Собственно как это все лучше преподнести пользователю? Куча кнопок? TableView? Или может быть есть еще какие-то варианты? Пишем на objective-c для iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Яб заюзал `UICollectionView` и какую-нибудь логику пагинации, ну к примеру по 300 картинок, потом подргузка следующих 300, потом еще раз 300, но первые 300 удалить из памяти.

**Обновление**

Незнаю как ответить на Ваш вопрос, могу посоветовать почитать документацию по следующим классам: `UICollectionView` , `UICollectionViewCell` , `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, `UICollectionViewController`, `UICollectionViewUpdateItem` ,`UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`, `UICollectionViewTransitionLayout`, `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext`,'UICollectionViewFlowLayoutInvalidationContext'.  Из пагинаторов понравилась вот эта либа: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nmpaginator,  для динамической загрузки и просмотра в фулскрине картинок FSImageViewer. больше мне нечем Вам помочь

Comment: Не, картинки должны показываться по одной на выбор пользователя.

Comment: ну, а где он должен их выбирать?

Comment: Вот в этом и весь вопрос..

Comment: ну и я не могу понять чем `UICollectionView` не угодил?

Comment: Тем, что если он будет грузить пачками, то это съест много трафика. А если телефон в сети эдж, а не 3Г? Это же долго все будет, имхо

Comment: он будет грузить так как Вы запрограммируете. ;)

Comment: Хм... т.е. можно будет сделать так, чтобы он грузил картинку, например по тапу на нее и сразу открывал ее на весь экран? Я даже не думал об этом и никогда им не пользовался =)

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

Я бы разбил картинки на тематические группы и вывел скроллингом заголовки групп. >1000 картинок в таблице, по-моему, трудно воспринимаемы пользователем. По-иному говоря, он вряд ли дойдет до конца этого длиннющего списка)